# I am not able to get individual percentage in angular. as i am working with dynamic form array

Tags: arrays, angular, forms, dynamic

[image]

### Logic(i have tried):

```js
    Total() {

      console.log();
      var maxval = parseInt(this.ProgramForm.value.Pr_Value);

      var funded = parseInt(this.ProgramForm.value.funder_details.reduce((sum, val) => sum + parseInt(val.funded), 0));
      this.sub = 0;
      console.log(maxval + ' ' + funded);
      // console.log(this.ProgramForm.value.funder_details);
      if (funded < maxval) {
        this.isDisabled = true;
        this.sub = maxval - funded;
        console.log(this.sub)
        this.per = (funded / maxval) * 100;

        console.log(this.sub);
      }
      //else if(this.ProgramForm.value.percentage < 100){
      //   this.isDisabled = true;
      //   console.log(this.ProgramForm.value.funder_details.percentage);

      //   // console.log(this.sub);
      // }
      else {
        this.isDisabled = true;
      }

    }
```

### this is my form array

[check the angular html code](https://angular-y9u7om.stackblitz.io)

This is my form array HTML code. Its is dynamically generating the fields i.e. run-time
I have tried the logic but I want individual percentage but it is calculating the overall percentage.

Comment: how does your form look like? how are you adding these elements to the `formArray`?

Comment: @Aravind i have put my angular html code in stackbltiz link

Comment: @GRV the stackblitz link you shared has some error. It seems you have not added the component.ts code.